# Acknowledge 3rd party figures using Bibtex copyright key

Tags: bibtex, copyright

Usually, in `.bib` entry for a publication for instance by IEEE, ACM, a field can be added called "`copyright`" to include copyright information. Then, in the LaTeX document being prepared using book class and BibTeX, if a figure from previously published work is used as it is, how do you make an entry of something like:

> Figure XX reproduced with permission from `\cite{key}{copyright}`?

P.S. I am trying to avoid usage of `biblatex` package. Is there a quick fix just by using BibTeX?

Comment: I'm not aware of a BibTeX solution that lets you extract arbitrary content from a `.bib` file. I guess you would have to write your own `.bst` file (or modify an existing one) to write the contents of the `copyright` field to the `.bbl` *and* fiddle with a few internal commands that implement `\cite` and friends to obtain the data from the `.bbl` file and print it. I'm not saying that this is impossible, but I am saying it is going to be a bit of work. And you will have to decide whether the effort is worth it.

Comment: The exact implementation of course depends on the bibliography package (`cite`, `natbib`, ...) and style you use.

Comment: @moewe The tool exists…

Comment: @egreg In the back of my mind I kind of remembered a package written by you, but I could not remember the name and only found `bibentry` (which is neither yours, nor does it help a lot here) ...

Answer (score 6):

This is not impossible, but it requires a bit of fiddling with your `.bst` file. As it turns out I had forgotten about `usebib` (see egreg's answer) which already provides an interface for reading fields from `.bib` files. `usebib` uses a different method, it parses the `.bib` file directly with key-value syntax.

---

What makes this difficult is the fact that LaTeX does not read the `.bib` file directly itself. Instead BibTeX reads the `.bib` file and produces a sorted and formatted bibliography in the `.bbl` file. This `.bbl` file is then read by LaTeX and becomes the bibliography. (You can read more about this in [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).)

Since LaTeX itself never reads the `.bib` file one way to get the `copyright` information to LaTeX is to instruct BibTeX to include it in the `.bbl` file - not in a way visible in the output, just in a way that LaTeX can use. There is one difficulty with this approach: the `.bbl` file is read and processed when you write `\bibliography` in your `.tex` file. In all likeliness this is after the point where you want to cite the copyright data. We can try to work around this limitation by doing what `natbib` does to obtain the author and year data for author year citations: We add a command in the `.bbl` file that when executed writes the data to the `.aux` file. Upon the next LaTeX run the copyright data is available in the `.aux` file and will be processed at the beginning of the document, before any copyright citation is issued. The data is then available whenever you want to cite the copyright info.

The first step is to modify your `.bst` file to pass on the copyright data.
The exact modifications needed depend on the `.bst` file, but the process should be almost identical for most styles.

Under https://gist.github.com/moewew/0fefe855a269f5eed06a5b6260f23bfd you can find a modified version of `plain.bst` called `plain-copy.bst` that includes the copyright data in the `.bbl`. The necessary changes were

1. Add `copyright` to the list of known fields in the first argument of `ENTRY`
2. Make sure that the data is written out. In `plain.bst` that was achieved by modifying the function `output.bibitem` from

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
   { newline$
     "\bibitem{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}" write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
   { newline$
     "\bibitem{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}\makeatletter\cc@bbl@citecopyright{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}{" write$
     copyright write$
     "}\makeatother" write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
   }
   ```

The patch for the change is

```
--- plain.bst   2010-12-09 04:18:56.000000000 +0100
+++ plain-copy.bst  2018-06-13 10:10:10.732783800 +0200
@@ -1,12 +1,11 @@
-% BibTeX standard bibliography style `plain'
-   % Version 0.99b (8-Dec-10 release) for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later.
+% BibTeX standard bibliography style `plain-copy'
+   % based on `plain.bst' version 0.99b (8-Dec-10 release)
    % Copyright (C) 1984, 1985, 1988, 2010 Howard Trickey and Oren Patashnik.
    % Unlimited copying and redistribution of this file are permitted as long as
    % it is unmodified.  Modifications (and redistribution of modified versions)
    % are also permitted, but only if the resulting file is renamed to something
    % besides btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, and abbrv.bst.
    % This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.
-   % The file btxbst.doc has the documentation for this style.

 ENTRY
   { address
@@ -31,6 +30,7 @@
     type
     volume
     year
+    copyright
   }
   {}
   { label }
@@ -86,7 +86,11 @@
 { newline$
   "\bibitem{" write$
   cite$ write$
-  "}" write$
+  "}\makeatletter\cc@bbl@citecopyright{" write$
+  cite$ write$
+  "}{" write$
+  copyright write$
+  "}\makeatother" write$
   newline$
   ""
   before.all 'output.state :=
```

Then you need to add a few macros to your document preamble.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cc@bbl@citecopyright}[2]{%
  \if@filesw
    \write\@auxout{\string\cc@aux@citecopyright{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\cc@aux@citecopyright}[2]{%
  \csgdef{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\citecopyright}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}
    {\textbf{?}%
     \PackageWarning{'citecopyright'}{%
       Copyright field for #1 not found}}
    {\csuse{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}}}
\makeatother
```

`\cc@bbl@citecopyright` is the command for the `.bbl` file and writes its argument to the `.aux` file and calls `\cc@aux@citecopyright` on them. `\cc@aux@citecopyright` simply saves the data for later use, so that `\citecopyright` can access it.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  copyright = {IEEE},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cc@bbl@citecopyright}[2]{%
  \if@filesw
    \write\@auxout{\string\cc@aux@citecopyright{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\cc@aux@citecopyright}[2]{%
  \csgdef{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\citecopyright}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}
    {\textbf{?}%
     \PackageWarning{'citecopyright'}{%
       Copyright field for #1 not found}}
    {\csuse{cc@data@citecopyright@#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{A duck}\label{fig:duck}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:duck} reproduced with permission from \citecopyright{appleby} \cite{appleby}

\bibliographystyle{plain-copy}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This file needs to be compiled at least with

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

[image]

---

You say that you don't want to switch to `biblatex`, but just for fun here is the `biblatex` solution.

Here we "only" need to tell Biber about our new field `copyright`. This is done via the datamodel file `copyright.dbx`. We declare `copyright` as literal list and make it known to all data types.

Then you can use `\citelist{<key>}{copyright}` to obtain the copyright information. But I find it nicer to define a dedicated macro `\citecopyright` and use that.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  copyright = {IEEE},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{copyright.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{copyright.dbx}[2018/06/13 Copyright field for biblatex]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=literal]{copyright}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{copyright}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, datamodel=copyright]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecopyright}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printlist{copyright}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{A duck}\label{fig:duck}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:duck} reproduced with permission from \citecopyright{appleby} \cite{appleby}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the duck side - we have cookies :)

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for `usebib`. You can define a new bib field `copyright` and then you can print the field's content with

```
\usebibentry{<bib key>}{copyright}
```

Full example (picture like in moewe's answer).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  copyright = {IEEE},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{usebib} % the main one

% the next two are just for the picture
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

% load the bib file
\newbibfield{copyright}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{A duck}\label{fig:duck}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:duck} is \textcopyright\usebibentry{appleby}{copyright}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

In your document, use the name of the right `.bib` file instead of `\jobname`.

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm using usebibentry. Thanks for MWE.